# Timestamp out of range - PostgreSQL with OLEDB .NET

Tags: sql, .net, postgresql, timestamp, oledb

We have a .Net application which stores data in PostgreSQL. We have a perfectly working code with PostgreSQL 8.3 and now we are trying to upgrade our PostgreSQL server from version 8.3 to 9.3 and our code seems to break.

For connecting PostgeSQL we are using `OLEDB`.

The issue we are getting is “`Timestamp out of range`”. When looked through the logs we are receiving weird timestamp “`152085-04-28 06:14:51.818821`”.

From our application We are trying to pass a value from .Net code to postgreSQL function which is of type timestamp. As we are using OLEDB for connections, we are using parameter type as `OleDbType.DBTimeStamp` and sending date time value from .Net code. This code works in PostgreSQL 8.3 but breaks in 9.3. From the logs of Postgresql 9.3 the parameter value which we are receiving is “`152085-04-28 06:14:51.818821`”.

We tried to execute the same function using `npgsql` provider from sample .net code by passing Date time value and giving parameter type as `NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTZ` with this we are getting correct results. From the logs of PostgreSQL the parameter values received at the function is shown as “`E'2014-01-30 12:17:50.804220'::timestamptz`”.
Tried in other versions of postgresql i.e. 9.1, 9.2, 9.3 and was breaking in all these versions.

Any Idea why this is breaking in other versions of PostgreSQL when perfectly working in 8.3?

Thanks

Comment: Please show full text of the exact, copied and pasted error message along with the exact text of the SQL query that resulted in that error. You might need to set `log_statement = all` in `postgresql.conf.`

Comment: @Craig Ringer I have set log_statement = all before and after setting that I have got the date time values receiving at postgreSQL like this "152085-05-06 13:22:56.498769". I am executing a function which accepts Timestamp values from .NET code I'm sending DateTime values. please see this code :
Instruction = \"Test\".\"TestFunction\"";
Parameters.Add("pDate", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp, DateTime.Now);
Parameters.Add("pDateRangeMax", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp, DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

Comment: Edit your question ("edit" link, under the tags) to add more info. In your question you can format it readably. And *show the exact query* and *exact error text* when you do so.

Comment: @CraigRinger I have figured out why I'm getting Timestamp out of Ranger error. The value received at the postgrSQL 9.3 is "**152085-05-06 13:22:56.498769**" instead of DateTime ex: "2014-01-31 14:26:56" I just wanted to know why i'm not receiving correct values from .NET code when using OLEDB connection, **The same code works for PostgreSQL 8.3 version and gives correct results**. I wrote a sample program using 'npgsql' and received correct values from .NET code and hence confirmed that function at PostgreSQL are working fine.

Comment: Try to obtain the same timestamp column by another frontend, preferably psql. (timestamps in pg8.3 and before were (by default) implemented internally as doubles; your driver may still assume this) If this appears to work update your driver / frontend program, too.BTW: how did you upgrade your data?

Comment: @joop The driver shouldn't ever see the raw timestamp format, since they're exchanged with clients in a text representation. There _is_ a binary mode in the protocol but it's little-used. Good thought, though, the change to integer timestamps does occur at the same time the user has issues.

Comment: @joop I have taken backup of Database in PostgreSQL 8.3 and uninstalled 8.3 and then installed 9.3 and restored the data

Comment: Then first try to obtain the column values using a correct frontend. In psql (or pgadmin): `select the_column from the_table;` if the result is a correct date, the flaw is in your frontend or (odbc?) driver.